# Adjusting Voltage regulator with PWMed optocoupler

Tags: voltage-regulator, pwm, dac, optoelectronics

I have LD1084V adjustable voltage regulator powering servo and want to control its output from MCU. Optocoupler should behave as variable resistor so my thinking was :
[image: schema]

I am mainly concerned with gray rectangle area - other part works fine so far.

MCU is Attiny85.
I've measured current at RP2 when running servo at full speed (by voltmeter only) and it was 0.9 mA max.
Optocoupler should bypass RP2, when fully open.
R1 is for diode protection.
R3+C1 should smooth PWM to somehow-steady analog voltage.

I've used lot of internet to put it together, but I am still a noob ... so could as well missunderstood some parts all together.

I didn't tested it yet (I expertly killed my only opto at hand, so waiting for replacement).

I want to ask if my thinking is right and if this can be done with transistor-based opto (photodiode ones are a bit pricey)?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to vary the power supply voltage to the servo?   If it is a standard servo like is used in remote controlled cars and airplane models, then you should just give it its rated voltage and leave it at that.

Comment: I need ability for users to adjust torque moment.

Comment: What kind of servo is it?

Comment: https://www.jxservo.cz/JX-servo-PDI-5521MG-360-digital-55g-20kg-d119.htm

Comment: You wouldn't normally mess with the power supply to such a servo.  Why do you want to limit the torque?

Comment: Servo itself acts as adjustment device on wearable component. Modifying turque should set a 'grip' that is comfortable for individual user.

Comment: I don't think that will work as you'd like.  That kind of servo tends to get all "wiggly" when you reduce the power.  Rather than "hold less tight" it is more like "can't maintain a grip."  It'll likely "pump" - grip harder and softer  rapidly.

Comment: I'd try it with a simple potentiometer to see if it does what you want before you tackle the optocoupler.

Comment: I already did some tests with potenciometer and it worked fine .. it pumps a bit, as you said, but it is acceptable.

Comment: Also ... I should mention it is not ON all the time - once a grip is set, it is usually turned off.

Comment: you could ditch the LDO and use a BJT as a voltage follower linear "power supply". Then all you need to do is feed your smoothed PWM to an opamp to amplify/scale 3.3v to the line voltage, leaving you with an adjustable 0-(line - 0.7v)v linear supply.

Comment: that's really good point and 0.7V is much better than my current 1.5V, thanks ... little problem (partially my fault, sorry) is that where there is 1K R2 on output pin in schema, there is planned to be DIP switch with resistor array to 'select' voltage range for that variable resistance in question (to support different servos). Not sure if that's doable with BJT approach. I deleted that part because it is in working now and seemed too off topic to me - oops

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to start again from scratch. Your servo for sure doesn't need a linear PSU, you could use a buck converter for that purpose. Next thing that you do want to have is a LDO with PWM adjusting as it makes a PSU with lots of noise and lots of heat dissipation, a useless power supply. Further it is not clear why the galvanic isolation is needed.

Comment: Galvanic is not needed, anything that can act as variable resistor is acceptable.
Noise should be mostly taken by low-pass filter R3+C1. Heat is in OK level so far.
For this concrete application LDO seems to be right choice. But I may overlook something.